Why is Emacs recompiling some packages on every startup?
Every time I start Emacs, it creates an *Async-native-compile-log* buffer with the following contents:
Compiling /usr/share/emacs/29.4/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-loaddefs.el.gz...
uncompressing cl-loaddefs.el.gz...
uncompressing cl-loaddefs.el.gz...done
Compilation finished.

It does not happen with emacs -q, so I was tempted to blame my config, buuuut...
It still happens even if I entirely delete my config (if all of ~/.emacs, ~/.emacs.el, ~/.emacs.d/init.el, and ~/.config/emacs/init.el are missing), with both emacs and emacs --no-site-file.
What's causing this, and how do I make it stop? (Either "how do I fix it?" if it's a (symptom of a) problem, or "how do I filter just this noise from the (potentially useful) async native compile information?")

Turns out, there's a bug in native-compile-async-skip-p (I'm on Emacs 29.4).
It receives the filename to compile (for example /usr/share/emacs/29.4/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-loaddefs.el.gz), and checks if the corresponding .elc file name is already in the ignore-list (and cl-loaddefs.elc is in there):
      (gethash (file-name-with-extension file "elc") comp--no-native-compile)

But when file ends with .el.gz, the result of (file-name-with-extension file "elc") is a file name ending with .el.elc instead of just .elc. The wrong extension causes it to not match, and so native-compile-async-skip-p fails to notice that it should ignore this file.
(With a more complex config, you'll also see this bug surface for other files that aren't supposed to be compiled but which end with .el.gz. For example, I see it with tramp-loaddefs.el.gz.)
Presumably this will eventually be fixed upstream, but in the meantime, we can advise native-compile-async-skip-p in our config to fix this. For example:
(defun fixed-native-compile-async-skip-p
        (native-compile-async-skip-p file load selector)
    (let* ((naive-elc-file (file-name-with-extension file "elc"))
           (elc-file       (replace-regexp-in-string
                               "\\.el\\.elc$" ".elc" naive-elc-file)))
        (or (gethash elc-file comp--no-native-compile)
            (funcall native-compile-async-skip-p file load selector))))

(advice-add 'native-compile-async-skip-p
    :around 'fixed-native-compile-async-skip-p)

P.S. Despite this bug, the repeated compilation isn't a problem, so if you don't mind the noise of the buffer always appearing in your buffer list even if no "real"/new native compilation is happening, it's fine to ignore it. What's happening is that cl-loaddefs.el contains a file-local no-native-compile variable set to t, so the native compilation never actually creates an .eln file for it in your ~/.emacs.d/eln-cache directory, so the next time Emacs runs it detects it as still needing to be compiled.

Please M-x report-emacs-bug if you can't see an existing bug report for it.

At a glance, it sounds like https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=57627 but if so it would be a regression, as that bug was marked as fixed in version 29.1.

@phils thanks! I looked a bit closer: 57627 discussed and fixed the problem just for *.el files, but overlooked the *.el.gz case.

Idk when I'll get around to filing a bug report, probably not soon, but I welcome anyone else to do it with the information from here (I am fine with not getting credit for it, and if copyright is a concern I've already done the GNU assignment paperwork).

Would you mind replying to Andrea's latest comment in the re-opened bug for the aforementioned link?  Apparently it can't be replicated in Emacs 30.
